# Connecting variables for analysis

Tags: javascript, adobe, analytics

I experiment local the Adobe analytics. From documentation I try to implement this

In the Adobe image request that occurs on the page view, if you are using dynamic variables to copy the value of Custom Traffic
1 to Custom Conversion 1, you would see `v1=D=c1`.

How can I make it between 3 pages?

Comment: are you asking how to set a variable with the same value from page to page?

Comment: @CrayonViolent Yes this is what I try to do.

Comment: Okay well it sounds like you should make use of Adobe's [getAndPersistValue](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/getAndPersistValue.html) plugin, or you could just write your own code to set and read a cookie

Comment: @CrayonViolent is it possible to collect the b/ss call of adobe which we can see in browser and save the results locally without need to open the browser and type the url? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169246/tracking-specific-server-calls-and-save-results-locally

Comment: The point of Adobe Analytics (and any other tracking tool e.g. Google Analytics) is to track visitor activity on your site.  You decide what kind of activity you want to be tracked and you implement the tracking code accordingly.  If you want to capture that without going through the physical motion - I assume to automate testing - you will need to use a tool that can automate website activity, something like Selenium.